# Bash export: not a valid identifier

Tags: bash, ls-colors

I have a Raspberry PI running Raspbian.
By default the shell presents itself colorfully formatted, and I wanted to change a little bit these settings, manipulating the `LS_COLORS` variable, by doing this:

```
LS_COLORS="ow=01;90:di=01;90"
export LS_COLORS
```

The problem presents when I log in via ssh. Before prompting the usual, it displays this:

```
-bash: export: `LS_COLORS:': not a valid identifier
```

I have looked both in the `~/.bashrc` and `~/.bash_profile` (actually this one does not exist).
I didn't change anything in the `.bashrc`, and nothing points directly to LS_COLORS.
I also tried to `$ unset LS_COLORS` but nothing changes at the next login.
Thanks for your help!

`.bashrc` for reference:

```
# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files (in the package bash-doc)
# for examples

# If not running interactively, don't do anything
[ -z "$PS1" ] && return

# don't put duplicate lines or lines starting with space in the history.
# See bash(1) for more options
HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth

# append to the history file, don't overwrite it
shopt -s histappend

# for setting history length see HISTSIZE and HISTFILESIZE in bash(1)
HISTSIZE=1000
HISTFILESIZE=2000

# check the window size after each command and, if necessary,
# update the values of LINES and COLUMNS.
shopt -s checkwinsize

# If set, the pattern "**" used in a pathname expansion context will
# match all files and zero or more directories and subdirectories.
#shopt -s globstar

# make less more friendly for non-text input files, see lesspipe(1)
#[ -x /usr/bin/lesspipe ] && eval "$(SHELL=/bin/sh lesspipe)"

# set variable identifying the chroot you work in (used in the prompt below)
if [ -z "$debian_chroot" ] && [ -r /etc/debian_chroot ]; then
    debian_chroot=$(cat /etc/debian_chroot)
fi

# set a fancy prompt (non-color, unless we know we "want" color)
case "$TERM" in
    xterm-color) color_prompt=yes;
esac

# uncomment for a colored prompt, if the terminal has the capability; turned
# off by default to not distract the user: the focus in a terminal window
# should be on the output of commands, not on the prompt
force_color_prompt=yes

if [ -n "$force_color_prompt" ]; then
    if [ -x /usr/bin/tput ] && tput setaf 1 >&/dev/null; then
  # We have color support; assume it's compliant with Ecma-48
  # (ISO/IEC-6429). (Lack of such support is extremely rare, and such
  # a case would tend to support setf rather than setaf.)
  color_prompt=yes
    else
  color_prompt=no
    fi
fi

if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\] \[\033[01;34m\]\w \$\[\033[00m\] '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
fi
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt

# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
case "$TERM" in
xterm*|rxvt*)
    PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
    ;;
*)
    ;;
esac

# enable color support of ls and also add handy aliases
if [ -x /usr/bin/dircolors ]; then
    test -r ~/.dircolors && eval "$(dircolors -b ~/.dircolors)" || eval "$(dircolors -b)":
    alias ls='ls --color=auto'
    #alias dir='dir --color=auto'
    #alias vdir='vdir --color=auto'

    alias grep='grep --color=auto'
    alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
    alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
fi

# some more ls aliases
#alias ll='ls -l'
#alias la='ls -A'
#alias l='ls -CF'

# Alias definitions.
# You may want to put all your additions into a separate file like
# ~/.bash_aliases, instead of adding them here directly.
# See /usr/share/doc/bash-doc/examples in the bash-doc package.

if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi

# enable programmable completion features (you don't need to enable
# this, if it's already enabled in /etc/bash.bashrc and /etc/profile
# sources /etc/bash.bashrc).
if [ -f /etc/bash_completion ] && ! shopt -oq posix; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
fi
```

Comment: Check your script for DOS line endings. I suspect you are actually trying to export `LS_COLORS\r`.

Comment: Somewhere you have `LS_COLORS:` -- with a colon

Comment: Any idea where to look?

Comment: You can run `grep 'LS_COLORS:' ~/.*` in your home directory on the Raspberry PI to try and find where the reported error happens.

Comment: Please post the contents of `~/.bashrc`

Comment: Check in /etc withbgrep too for LS_COLORS.

Comment: Check the scripts in `/etc/profile.d/`. One of them might actually contain `LS_COLORS:`.

Answer (score 1):

This line looks fishy:

```
test -r ~/.dircolors && eval "$(dircolors -b ~/.dircolors)" || eval "$(dircolors -b)":
```

Sure you want the colon at EOL?

Comment: Actually this line and the entire `.bashrc` file are the original ones shipping with Raspbian. I didn't edit any of those.